# OneSignal Player ID's (iOS)

Tags: ios, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, onesignal

Using OneSignal and firebase, I was able to store the user's playerIDs as a node. In the event of sending a notification to multiple users, I've set up an array filled with each playerID (String).

When I'm trying to post a notification, I'm getting this error:

```
Incorrect player_id format in include_player_ids (not a valid UUID): [\"8695719e-c92b-4f1d-8364-4d67f4eb4aff\"]
```

Heres the line of code:

```
"include_player_ids": [playerIDArrayOfStrings]
```

In the error, they're showing that there are two extra `\`s in the array. How can I get rid of those so that it can take the proper value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed a guard statement to safely unwrap the playerID's and then add them to the array.